# Performance Impact of Throwing Exceptions in an Azure WorkerRole

Tags: exception, azure, azure-worker-roles

Is there any negative performance impact to throwing and catching exceptions on an Azure worker role running many threads?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but just in case anyone was looking:  Yes.

Just like any other .NET host, if you throw a ton of Exceptions, you will experience a (sometimes dramatic) performance impact.  Exceptions should be for 'exceptional' things and not every day code paths and known failure conditions.

Worse case scenario for Windows Azure:  you will cripple your service.  If you do not handle an Exception in Windows Azure, it will cause the RoleEntryPoint to recycle.  If you do this a lot, you will see the RoleCycling status and you have effectively killed your service.